# Pandas - can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

`df_melt`:

```
    MatchID GameWeek        Date                      Team  Home               AgainstTeam
0     46605        1  2019-08-09                 Liverpool  Home              Norwich City
1     46605        1  2019-08-09              Norwich City  Away                 Liverpool
2     46606        1  2019-08-10           AFC Bournemouth  Home          Sheffield United
3     46606        1  2019-08-10          Sheffield United  Away           AFC Bournemouth
4     46607        1  2019-08-10                   Burnley  Home               Southampton
..      ...      ...         ...                       ...   ...                       ...
533   46871       27  2020-02-23                   Watford  Away         Manchester United
534   46872       27  2020-02-22          Sheffield United  Home  Brighton and Hove Albion
535   46872       27  2020-02-22  Brighton and Hove Albion  Away          Sheffield United
536   46873       27  2020-02-22               Southampton  Home               Aston Villa
537   46873       27  2020-02-22               Aston Villa  Away               Southampton
```

and, for player matches, `df_pm`:

```
                                       Player  GameWeek  Minutes  ... CloseShotCreated TotalShotCreated  HeadersCreated
PlayerMatchesDetailID                                             ...                                                  
1                                     Alisson         1       90  ...                0                0               0
2                             Virgil van Dijk         1       90  ...                0                0               0
3                                Joseph Gomez         1       90  ...                0                1               0
4                            Andrew Robertson         1       90  ...                0                1               0
5                      Trent Alexander-Arnold         1       90  ...                3                3               1
...                                       ...       ...      ...  ...              ...              ...             ...
15053                             Matty James        22        0  ...                0                0               0
15054                             Matty James        23        0  ...                0                0               0
15055                             Matty James        24        0  ...                0                0               0
15056                             Matty James        25        0  ...                0                0               0
15057                             Matty James        26        0  ...                0                0               0
```

Now, I'm trying to iterate through `df_pm` and find items given some conditions on `df_melt`, like so:

```
#Instantiate an empty list
match_ids = []
home_away = []
dates = []

#For each row in the player matches dataframe...
for row in df_pm.itertuples():
    #Look up the match id from the team matches dataframe
    team = row.ForTeam
    againstteam = row.AgainstTeam
    gameweek = row.GameWeek

    match_id = df_melt.loc[(df_melt['GameWeek']==gameweek)
                          &(df_melt['Team']==team)
                          &(df_melt['AgainstTeam']==againstteam),
                          'MatchID'].item()

    date = df_melt.loc[(df_melt['GameWeek']==gameweek)
                          &(df_melt['Team']==team)
                          &(df_melt['AgainstTeam']==againstteam),
                          'Date'].item()

    home = df_melt.loc[(df_melt['GameWeek']==gameweek)
                          &(df_melt['Team']==team)
                          &(df_melt['AgainstTeam']==againstteam),
                          'Home'].item()

    #Add it to the list
    match_ids.append(match_id)
    home_away.append(home)
    dates.append(date)
```

But for all iterations, even though I print 'team', againstteam' and 'gameweek', I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tableau_data_generation.py", line 155, in <module>
    'MatchID'].item()
  File "/Users/me/anaconda2/envs/data_science/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 652, in item
    return self.values.item()
ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
```

...suggesting the item is not there.

But when I print the full dataframe `df_melt`, like so:

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):  # more options can be specified also
    print(df_melt, df_melt.shape)
```

I get `(538, 6)` and can see all data is there, with no flaws.

---

When I check for types, I see:

`df_melt`:

```
MatchID        object
GameWeek       object
Date           object
Team           object
Home           object
AgainstTeam    object
```

`df_pm`:

```
Player                 object
GameWeek                int64
Minutes                 int64
ForTeam                object
AgainstTeam            object
Goals                   int64
ShotsOnTarget           int64
ShotsInBox              int64
CloseShots              int64
TotalShots              int64
Headers                 int64
GoalAssists             int64
ShotOnTargetCreated     int64
ShotInBoxCreated        int64
CloseShotCreated        int64
TotalShotCreated        int64
HeadersCreated          int64
```

---

So there is a mismatch of types here.

---

If I add the following line of code before iteration is performed:

```
df_melt['GameWeek'] = pd.to_numeric(df_melt['GameWeek'])
```

I sucessfully print dozens of 'match_id', 'date', and 'home' for the first row in `df_pm.itertuples()` (which was not being printed before I added that line), only to break again at second row with the same error:

```
ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
```

---

How do I fix this?

---

**Note**: This is what follows the code above.

```
def matchid_lookup(player, date, team, gameweek):
    try:
        try:
            return df_pm.loc[(df_pm['Date']==date)
                        &(df_pm['Player']==player), 'MatchID'].item()
        except:
            return df_pm.loc[(df_pm['Date']==date)
                        &(df_pm['ForTeam']==team), 'MatchID'].iloc[0]
    except:
        return df_pm.loc[(df_pm['GameWeek']==gameweek)
                        &(df_pm['Player']==player), 'MatchID'].item()

#Declare the list as a column in the player matches df
df_pm['MatchID']=match_ids
df_pm['Date']=pd.to_datetime(dates)
df_pm['Home']=home_away
df_pm['Position']=df_pm['Player'].map(pos_lookup)

#Get the match IDs column first in the dataframe
cols = list(df_pm.columns)
new_cols = ['MatchID', 'Date', 'Home','Position'] + cols[:-4]
df_pm = df_pm[new_cols]

#Bring in stats from api table
#First, get key identifiers into the api table to facilitate joining
df_api_stats['Player'] = df_api_stats['PlayerID'].map(player_lookup)
df_api_stats['Team'] = df_api_stats['PlayerID'].map(team_lookup)    
df_api_stats['MatchID'] = df_api_stats.apply(lambda x: matchid_lookup(x['Player'],
                                                                      x['Date'],
                                                                      x['Team'],
                                                                      x['GameWeek']), axis=1)
api_cols = ['Player', 'MatchID', 'BPS', 'MinutesPlayed',
            'CleanSheet', 'Saves', 'NetTransfersIn',
            'SelectedBy', 'Points', 'Price']

df_api_cols = df_api_stats[api_cols]
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213656/discussion-on-question-by-8-bit-borges-pandas-can-only-convert-an-array-of-siz).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so there are some Date from `df_api_stats` that are not in `df_pm`, you can see it with:

```
print (set(pd.to_datetime(df_api_stats['Date'])) - set(pd.to_datetime(df_pm['Date'])))
{Timestamp('2020-01-29 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-02-28 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-02-29 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-03-01 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-03-07 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-03-08 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-03-09 00:00:00')}
```

I'm not sure what you want to do with missing values but to avoid the method failing, you can add an except and return nan if none of the possibility matches.

```
def matchid_lookup(player, date, team, gameweek):
    try:
        try:
            return df_pm.loc[(df_pm['Date']==date)
                        &(df_pm['Player']==player), 'MatchID'].item()
        except:
            return df_pm.loc[(df_pm['Date']==date)
                        &(df_pm['ForTeam']==team), 'MatchID'].iloc[0]
    except:
        try:
            return df_pm.loc[(df_pm['GameWeek']==gameweek)
                            &(df_pm['Player']==player), 'MatchID'].item()
        except:
            return np.nan
```

Note: just before the `for` loop that caused problem earlier, don't forget to do this:

```
df_melt['GameWeek'] = pd.to_numeric(df_melt['GameWeek'])
df_melt[['Team', 'AgainstTeam']] = df_melt[['Team', 'AgainstTeam']]\
                                          .replace('AFC Bournemouth', 'Bournemouth')
```

Comment: brilliant, mate. you're a master. thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

```
 return self.values.item()
 ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
```

The above error is saying you have an array that has more than one element.  To be able to use .item() you should have just one value, so that it can be converted from an array into scalar.

Comment: is this an answer? looks like a comment...an answer would provide a solution